# Стоит ли делать большое количество перегрузок конструктора?

Tags: c++, классы

Имеется небольшой класс выполняющий роль контейнера визуального объекта:

```
#pragma once
#include "framework_element.h"

class container : public framework_element
{
protected:
    framework_element   *m_child_;
    ui_element          *m_parent_;

public:
    explicit container(gfx* gfx);
    explicit container(gfx& gfx);
    explicit container(gfx* gfx, framework_element* child);
    explicit container(gfx& gfx, framework_element& child);
    explicit container(gfx& gfx, framework_element  child);
    explicit container(gfx* gfx, ui_element* parent);
    explicit container(gfx& gfx, ui_element  parent);
    explicit container(gfx& gfx, ui_element& parent);
    explicit container(gfx* gfx, ui_element* parent, framework_element* child);
    explicit container(gfx& gfx, ui_element& parent, framework_element& child);
    explicit container(gfx& gfx, ui_element  parent, framework_element child);

    virtual void set_child(framework_element* child);
};
```

Как видно существуют почти всевозможные перегрузки за исключением копирования класса графики, который нельзя копировать. Стоит ли делать такое количество перегрузок конструктора дабы в дальнейшем это не доставило проблем?

К примеру, для чего тут конструктор который копирует визуальный объект? Что бы можно было налету создать временный визуальный объект не парясь о том кто и как им будет управлять, т.е. владельцем копии станет контейнер, который как пример покажет сообщение, и по истечению времени уничтожит данный объект.

Comment: А зачем везде используется explicit?

Comment: Что бы не генерировался оператор присваивания с классом графики

Comment: Вам нужен только один конструктор

Comment: @Yami, почему для это не использовать delete?

Comment: Тут совершенно непонятен принцип владения и опциональность передаваемых объектов. Передача по ссылке подразумевает, что владение не предается и что этот параметр не опциональный. Передача сырого указателя подразумевает в общем случае ничего (особенно когда полностью отсутствуют комментарии), но потенциально владение может передаваться. Передача по значению вообще непонятно почему разрешена (разрешенное копирование у такого объекта чревато object slicing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если оставить всего один коструктор

```
container(gfx* gfx, ui_element* parent = 0, framework_element* child = 0);
```

то при желании можно получить эффект любого из вами описанных конструкторов:

```
gfx g, *pg = &g;
ui_element p, *parent = &p;
framework fw, *pf = fw;
container cont1(pg);   // работает как  1 ий конструктор
container  cont2(&g);  // как 2
cont1.set_child(pf);   // как 3
cont2.set_child(&fw);  // 4
cont2.set_child(*pf);  // 5
container cont6(pg, &p); //6
container cont7(&g, parent); //7  используется  *parent
container cont8(&g, &p);    //8
container cont9(pg, parent, pf); // 9
container cont10(&g, &p, &fw);   // 10
container cont11(&g, parent, pf);    // 11  используется  *parent и *pf
```

Comment: Не лучше ли заменить `0` на `nullptr`?

Comment: @val,  nullptr  это макрос, который используется как альтернатива  макросу  NULL.   Он подразумывает указатель, который ни на что не указывает, и нужно присвоить только указателью.  У нас тут есть именованные указатели, и не зачем  применять макрос,  чтобы  сказать, что этот указатель ни на что не указывает.  Сам Страуструп рекомендовал использовать макросы только при случаи явной необходимости. Почему?.. Это уже другой вопрос и  об этом долго рассказать придется, тем более я  не смогу  лучше Страуструпа обьяснять, поэтому, для  получения ответа на этот вопрос, читайте его книги

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, `nullptr` — это не макрос, а экземпляр класса `std::nullptr_t`, у которого опредёлен оператор неявного преобразования в указатель. А вот `NULL` является макросом.